# Timer input field in IgGrid (feature:Updating ) editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

How can i get an Timer Validated Input field for each row ? 
datepicker/timer seems to be only a date picker and not a timer...
is there a way to manipulate the input fields by Jquery?

my table Columns `$scope.schedulerColumns = [{
            headerText: "GroupID", key: "Id", dataType: "number"
        },{
            headerText: "Time", key: "Time", dataType: "string"
        },
        {
            headerText: "Monday", key: "Mo", dataType: "bool"
        }, {
            headerText: "Tuesday", key: "Tu", dataType: "bool"
        }, {
            headerText: "Wednesday", key: "We", dataType: "bool"
        }, {
            headerText: "Thursday", key: "Th", dataType: "bool"
        }, {
            headerText: "Friday", key: "Fi", dataType: "bool"
        }];`

and my igGrid

```
    $("#schedulerTable").igGrid({
            columns: $scope.schedulerColumns,
            width: "87%",
            height: "300px",
            fixedHeaders: true,
            autoGenerateColumns: false,
            autofitLastColumn: true,
            renderCheckboxes: true,
            responseDataKey: "results",
            dataSource: $scope.schedulerData,
            updateUrl: "",
            primaryKey: 'Id',
            features: [
            {
                name: "Updating",
                generatePrimaryKeyValue: function (evt, ui) {
                    nextPrimarykey -= 1;
                    ui.value = nextPrimarykey;
                },
                enableAddRow: true,
                enableDeleteRow: true,
                editMode: "row",
                columnSettings: [
                   {
                       columnKey: "Id",
                       editorType: "numeric",
                       editorOptions: {
                           readOnly: true
                       }
                   }, {
                       columnKey: "Time",
                       editorType: "text",
                       editorOptions: {
                           required: true
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       columnKey: "Mo"

                   },
                   {
                       columnKey: "Tu"

                   },
                    {
                        columnKey: "We"

                    },
                    {
                        columnKey: "Th"

                    },
                    {
                        columnKey: "Fi"

                    }]
            }]
        });
```

I'm trying to create a Timer scheduler grid. and if i select the input field for timer then it should show like a datepicker for timer or something custom but i don't know how to call this input foreach row... best way would be that infragistic would have something ready for that but i can't find anything.